# CPU utilisation of Tomcat8 is high in Linux machine

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have a web portal and it is consuming high CPU. We have taken thread tump and checked the Catalina log during the time of issue and we couldn't find the root cause of the same. Is there any way that I can figure out.

Answer (score 0):

try [flamegraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) 
this helps you visualize cpu utilization by process.

this is frontend for [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) profile tool.